# Symfony 3.4 to 4.2 analog @ParamConverter class?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

It was a very convenient approach.

```
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
    ....     
        /**
         * @Route("/test/{id_object}", name="test")
         * @ParamConverter("ObjectEntity", class="Bundle:ObjectEntity", options={"id" = "id_object"})
         */
        public function editTest(ObjectEntity $ObjectEntity, Request $request) {
    .....

    }
```

How now to do the conversion of parameters?(Symfony 4)

Comment: What keeps you from using the exact same code?

Comment: You can also use /test/{ObjectEntity} directly without ParamConverter when it comes to id

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 4.2, to use ParamConverter, you musn't use the annotation @ParamConverter but directly reference to the type-hint of your entity.

So

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
.....
    /**
     * @Route("/test/{id_object}", name="test")
     * @ParamConverter("ObjectEntity", class="Bundle:ObjectEntity", options={"id" = "id_object"})
     */
    public function editTest(ObjectEntity $ObjectEntity, Request $request) {
.....

}
```

becomes

```
/**
* @Route("/test/{id}", name="test")
*/
public function editTest(ObjectEntity $obj, Request $req) {
    ....
    //A query is automatically runs to find the ObjectEntity which corresponds with the id sent in the Route
    //so $obj is the ObjectEntity whose $id property matches the id value in the Route, else if id value in the Route doesn't match with the ObjectEntity's id, you will have a 404 page.
}
```

Important : The parameter 'id' in the Route ("test/{id}") must be one property of ObjectEntity.(So use the same name ('id' here)).

Answer (score 0):

Same way as you did it on Symfony3 with ParamConverter. SensioFrameworkExtraBundle is not deprecated.

Comment: It is most definitely deprecated! https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/v5.5.1/src/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php#L314 :)

Comment: Only a specific setting is deprecated. Not entire bundle as you suggest.